# Laravel: Notify User on Job Completion

Tags: laravel

I am try to create a notification that alerts the user who ran a job upon completion.

The user does something that creates a job, once that job is complete, notify that user.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply dispatch an event at the and of your job.
Edit: When dispatching the job, you can pass the authenticated user:

```
Job::dispatch(auth()->user());


class Job implements ShouldQueue
{
  protected $user;
  
  public function __construct(User $user)
  {
    $this->user = $user;
  }

  public function handle(User $user)
  {
      // Your logic
      NotifyUser::dispatch($this->user);
  }
}
```

Or you can make use of job batches (https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#dispatching-batches) and use the `then()` callback to dispatch an event

Comment: That's the route I was planning on going down, however, I'm unsure how to pass the currently auth'd user into the job...

Comment: I've updated my answer with passing the authenticated user in the job

Comment: Is your question answered or do you need some more help?